# Read Label Array Information in Event Handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have an array label name title[i], and link[i].

```
Label[] title = new Label[100];
Label[] link = new Label[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
title[i] = new Label();
link[i] = new Label();
}
```

when i click the label title, i can get the link label information too.

```
title[i].MouseClick += new EventHandler(hover_title);
```

i try this code doesnt work.

```
public void hover_title(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                title[i].text=link[i].text;
            }
```

how i can get the label link text when i click the title label.

Comment: What does it mean **"i use sender as change the title[i]"** and what is **"link[i]"** you we're talking about **"title[i]"** all the time. Sorry, but that question is very unclear. Please update that.

Comment: Paste part of your code where you are declaring  "title" and "link" arrays;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like following should solve your problem.

```
    public void hover_title(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var label = sender as Label;
        int i = (title as IList).IndexOf(label);
        label.Text = link[i].Text;
    }
```

And remember, after you create a control you must give it a new location, in case of Label set a text, a new size (in case of Label you can set AutoSize property to true), and add it to parent control's Controls collection.

Comment: there an error , (Using the generic type 'IList<T>' requires 1 type arguments.)

Comment: I added namespace "using System.Collections;"

Comment: I cheked it. You can use generic IList<T> as well.  Use Label as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Label[] title = new Label[100];
Label[] link = new Label[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    title[j] = new Label();
    link[j] = new Label();
    title[j].MouseClick += (s, e) => title[j].Text = link[j].Text;
}
```